# Data through parse server heroku not being sent

Tags: android, android-studio, heroku, android-gradle-plugin, parse-server

I have changed the appid and master_key but the app run perfectly but when i refresh my dashbaord at heroku there was data fetch by it meaning my app is not yet communicating with heroku parse-server.  The url i have to remove back slash that was when it run but uptil is yet to send Data to Heroku

StarterApplication.java content

// Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

```
// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("o2smf97ce053b2f599c1d4e30a9d95646294a16e59a89mf")
        .clientKey("au2594YB0a4f17f20807054355edc884e038937e019f5b876")
        .server("http://instagrammaja.herokuapp.com/parse")
.build()
);

  ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
  gameScore.put("score", 1337);
  gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
  gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
  gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
          } else {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
          }
      }
  });
  ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
  //ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
```

the log.i message below

12-11 07:59:24.526 1590-1599/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18191(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 16MB/17MB, paused 6.097ms total 34.598ms

12-11 08:00:44.506 1590-1599/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16441(1855KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 16MB/17MB, paused 5.581ms total 26.502ms

12-11 08:01:18.664 1590-1744/? W/WifiMonitor:
 handleEvent unknown: 14 CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED

12-11 08:01:54.512 1590-1599/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17586(1999KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 17MB/17MB, paused 5.696ms total 43.270ms

12-11 08:02:04.610 1590-1599/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27086(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 74(1720KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 13MB/17MB, paused 6.123ms total 90.352ms